# How do I pass objects from one controller to another in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you pass an object built and submitted from one controller's `show` action to the `create` action of another controller while also retaining the instance variable of the former?

ItemsController:

```
def show
 @item = Item.friendly.find(params[:id])
 @trade = current_user.requested_trades.build
end
```

The `form_for` on my `show` page then makes a post request for `@trade`, with `:wanted_item` and `:trade_requester` as params.

TradesController:

```
def create
 @item = ???
 @trade = current_user.requested_trades.build
 if @trade.save
  format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: "success" }
 else
  format.html { redirect_to @item, notice "pick another number" }
 end
 etc...
end
```

Trade.rb:

```
belongs_to :trade_requester, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :trade_recipient, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :wanted_item, class_name: "Item"
belongs_to :collateral_item, class_name: "Item"
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :trades do
 member do
  post :accept
  post :reject
 end
end
```

Something about this feels wrong? Other questions on this subject seem to be about passing an object between different actions within the same controller - what I'm asking is not that.

Comment: You don't pass objects from one controller to another. That's simply not how it works.

Comment: @jvillian My `Item` `show` page has an option for making a `Trade` which takes the `Item` as one parameter. If I can't pass objects between controllers, how would I go about achieving this?

Comment: So, is there an association between `Item` and `Trade`? If so, please edit your question with that information. Also, what version of Rails are you on?

Comment: Question updated. I'm on Rails 4.2.4

Comment: So, is the item in show a wanted_item in TradeController#create? And you might as well show the relevant part of you routes.

Comment: Yes. The item in `show` is submitted as a trade param called `wanted_item`. Right now I'm achieving this in the form with `f.hidden_field :wanted_item, value: @item`. Post updated with route info.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think I would make my routes more like:

```
resources :wanted_items do 
  resources :trades, shallow: true do 
    member do 
      post :accept
      post :reject
    end
  end
end
```

Which would give you:

```
         accept_trade POST   /trades/:id/accept(.:format)                          trades#accept
         reject_trade POST   /trades/:id/reject(.:format)                          trades#reject
   wanted_item_trades GET    /wanted_items/:wanted_item_id/trades(.:format)        trades#index
                      POST   /wanted_items/:wanted_item_id/trades(.:format)        trades#create
new_wanted_item_trade GET    /wanted_items/:wanted_item_id/trades/new(.:format)    trades#new
           edit_trade GET    /trades/:id/edit(.:format)                            trades#edit
                trade GET    /trades/:id(.:format)                                 trades#show
                      PATCH  /trades/:id(.:format)                                 trades#update
                      PUT    /trades/:id(.:format)                                 trades#update
                      DELETE /trades/:id(.:format)                                 trades#destroy
         wanted_items GET    /wanted_items(.:format)                               wanted_items#index
                      POST   /wanted_items(.:format)                               wanted_items#create
      new_wanted_item GET    /wanted_items/new(.:format)                           wanted_items#new
     edit_wanted_item GET    /wanted_items/:id/edit(.:format)                      wanted_items#edit
          wanted_item GET    /wanted_items/:id(.:format)                           wanted_items#show
                      PATCH  /wanted_items/:id(.:format)                           wanted_items#update
                      PUT    /wanted_items/:id(.:format)                           wanted_items#update
                      DELETE /wanted_items/:id(.:format)                           wanted_items#destroy
```

Then in your `form_for`, I would do something like:

```
<% form_for wanted_item_trades_path(wanted_item: @wanted_item, trade: @trade) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

That `form_for` syntax may not be exactly right, so you may need to futz with it.

This will generate a url something like:

```
/wanted_items/3/trades
```

Naturally, the '3' is just made up. It'll be whatever your `@item.id` is.

When you post the form, you should have a `wanted_item_id` in your `params` of `3`. Then, in your TradesController, you'll do something like:

```
class TradesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @wanted_item = Item.find_by(id: params[:wanted_item_id])
    @trade = current_user.requested_trades.build(wanted_item: @wanted_item)
    if @trade.save
      format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: "success" }
    else
      format.html { redirect_to @item, notice "pick another number" }
    end
  end        

  ...

end
```

BTW, it looks like you're using friendly_id. So, you could tweak all of the above to use a `friendly_id` instead of `id`. I don't use friendly_id, so you'll have to sort that on your own.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I see a reason to add `:wanted_item` to my routes, though. Can you explain why you did that? The gist of what I'm setting up is this: user adds a `wanted_item` to a trade, then a `collateral_item` and then a `share`. The Item `show` view is the first page of this process. It's looking like I could just use two different controllers on that one view.

Comment: Hm. Pretty confusing - what you're trying to do, that is. And, knowing whether nested resources really makes sense (they may not) would take more information. But, hopefully, you can see that you don't pass objects around. You pass `id`s (either through hidden fields, URL elements, etc.) and use them to find records.